# setting of values for popupmenu in GUI

Tags: matlab

I have 2 Radiobuttons(Radio_1 and Radio_2) and a popupmenu in a GUI

I want:

1-when user selects Radio_1, the popupmenu was filled with 106, 111

AND

2-when user selects Radio_2, the popupmenu was filled with 240, 268

```
E1=get(handles.Radio_1,'Value');
E2=get(handles.Radio_2,'Value');
if(E1==1)
    set(handels.popupmenu_Food_Sources,'String',{'106','111'});
end
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `'String'` of `popupmenu` in the `radiobutton` ***Callback function*** (which is called when the `radiobutton` is checked or unchecked).

Here is a self-consistent code without using **GUIDE**:

```
function test

radio1 = uicontrol(...
    'Style','radiobutton', 'String', '1',...
    'Units','Normalized', 'Position', [0.4 0.5 0.2 0.1],...
    'Callback', @radioCall);

pop = uicontrol(...
    'Style','popupmenu', 'String', '0',...
    'Units','Normalized', 'Position', [0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1]);

    function radioCall(ev, sc)
        if get(radio1, 'Value')
            set (pop, 'String', {'1', '2', '3', '4'});
        else
            set (pop, 'String', {'0'});
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I use this code, but it was not useful. `function Radio_1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
E1str{1}='106';E1str{2}='111';E1str{3}='240';E1str{4}='268';E1str{5}='289';
set(handles.popupmenu_Food_Sources,'String',E1str); `

Comment: What happens when you try it? Do you get an error? Or just nothing happens when you check/uncheck the radio button?

Comment: just nothing happens when I check/uncheck the radio button

Comment: These codes also do not work: `function test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
set(handles.uipanel1,'SelectionChangeFcn',@uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn); `
`function uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata)
handles=guidata(hObject);
switch get(eventdata.Newvalue,'Tag')
    case 'radiobutton1'
    E1str{1}='1';E1str{2}='2';E1str{3}='3';E1str{4}='4';E1str{5}='5';
    set(handles.popupmenu1,'String',E1str);
    case 'radiobutton2'
...end`

Comment: I have just updated the answer, the sample code works fine for me. I am afraid that there is a problem in some other part of your code. Unfortunately when you are using **GUIDE** it's much harder for someone else to examine your code and detect the problem. So if the problem persists try to simplify your *GUI* as far as possible and post the whole code in your question(and not in comments please).

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:

```
function test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
str = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
set(handles.text1,'String',str(1));
set(handles.uipanel1,'SelectionChangeFcn',@uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn);
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
        val = get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value');
        str = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
        if val ==1
            set(handles.text1,'String',str(1));
        elseif val == 2
            set(handles.text1,'String',str(2));
        elseif val == 3
            set(handles.text1,'String',str(3));
        elseif val == 4
            set(handles.text1,'String',str(4));
        elseif val == 5
            set(handles.text1,'String',str(5));
        end
        guidata(hObject, handles);

function uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata)
handles=guidata(hObject);
switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag')
    case 'radiobutton1'
    E1str{1}='1';E1str{2}='2';E1str{3}='3';E1str{4}='4';E1str{5}='5';
    set(handles.popupmenu1,'String',E1str);
    case 'radiobutton2'
    E2str{1}='6';E2str{2}='7';E2str{3}='8';E2str{4}='9';E2str{5}='10';
    set(handles.popupmenu1,'String',E2str);
end
str = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
set(handles.text1,'String',str(1));
```